# Cannot draw in iPad Notes app using a finger

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app

I have an iPad Pro, 2nd generation with the iPadOS version 13.5.1 and I would like to draw or print on a page in the Notes app. I don't have an Apple Pencil but I should be able to do this with my finger. Below is a screenshot from my iPad of my attempt.  This question was [asked before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379712/cant-draw-in-notes-app) but the answer doesn't work for me.  Nothing I can do draws on a page. I've searched the web and found [this site](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/draw-or-use-handwriting-ipada87a6078/ipados) and [this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209498) that says this is possible but the descriptions don't work. Does anyone know how to make this work? It works fine on my iPhone 11 Pro.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution!!! It’s in the settings. [image: Toggle off “only draw with Apple Pencil”] Toggle off “only draw with Apple Pencil” ... simple yet hidden solution. Hope this helps everyone :-)

Comment: I didn’t think to check the app settings. Amazing and useful.

Comment: Well sadly it doesn’t work on the IPad Pro there is no setting available within the Notes settings menu

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that notes on iOS 13 does not want a finger to mark up on an iPad. It does work on the iPhone. Fingers are for navigation on the iPad build of Notes. I would recommend you draw in another app with your finger like Linea sketch.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/linea-sketch/id1094770251